# Using Cloudflare API and Python to make a plugin, multiple errors

Tags: python, cloudflare

This is the code I'm working with so far, after going around checking other posts to see for possible solutions, the included for statement allows for me to know there is 44 lists, but not what is in those lists, which key[0] nor the given key['rec_id'] work.
The key['rec_id'] is to get the id of the record. Is there something else I have to do?

```
j = r.post("https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html", params={'a': 'rec_load_all', 'tkn': conf.supybot.plugins.Cloudflare.APIToken, 'email': conf.supybot.plugins.Cloudflare.email, 'z': conf.supybot.plugins.Cloudflare.defaultdomain})
j = j.json()
#irc.reply(j.keys())
values = j['response']
values = values['recs']
values = values['objs']
for idx, key in enumerate(values):
    irc.reply(idx, key['rec_id'])
```

Comment: Tip:  That if-statement can be simplified if you use `in` like so: `if key in ('rec_id', 'name', 'content', 'display_content', 'zone_name', 'type'):`

Comment: alright, I'll edit my code for that, thanks for the comment